# Is it possible to port Swing into .Net world?

Tags: java, .net, swing

My question is it possible to port Swing into .Net world? Or a project like this has already been started.

If it is not possible, can anyone please shed some light on the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't translate on a line-for-line basis, to be sure, but it can be done, especially if your code is properly layered.

WinForms does a lot of things differently (IMO better, for the most part) that Swing, and WPF is even more different. It can be done, but it won't be easy.

Answer (score 0):

The closest that I have seen is [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/).  It is able to run java code under the CLR, including some AWT/Swing support.  The swing support is fairly limited, though, and probably inadequate for any large applications.